# Understanding imports from component pages in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am new to the Next.JS framework and do not fully understand the logic of importing data from a component page. For example, I have created a page like example.js in my components folder, where I am running an API that pulls data to a graph. Then, inside my index.js file, where I want my graph to be displayed, it is giving me a 'Unhandled Runtime Error', because the API function is not being triggered inside of example.js.

This is how I am importing the page in /pages/index.js:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Example = dynamic(() => import('../pages/example.js'))


//Later on inside of my return

  <Example />
```

And from my example.js page I am exporting as follows:

```
function Example(props) {
return <div>
... my code
}
```

Then below that, I have the following inside my example.js:

```
export default Example
```

Followed by my getStaticProps function:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

  const res = await fetch("")

  const data = await res.json()


  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      data: data.reverse(),
    },
  }
}
```

If I use this exact code on my index.js it functions properly. Any ideas as to why this doesn't run, and any solutions as to a fix?

**Edit for clarity:** My getStaticProps function is in my example.js file, and my issue is that it is not being triggered.

Comment: There is a typo `example(() => import('../components/example'))`, it should be `dynamic(() => import('../components/example'))`

Comment: Nice catch -- I accidentally typed that in here but my code had it written correctly.

Comment: by `index.js` do you mean `/pages/index.js`?

Comment: @bmdev Yes, I have just corrected it.

Comment: `getStaticProps` can only be used in a page. You'll have to move it to your `/pages/index`.

Comment: What did not work exactly? Does `getStaticProps` not get called when you navigate to the page? Is something inside it not working? You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @juliomalves I simply don't understand how I am supposed to run multiple API calls on a single page -- so I tried to do getStaticProps from another page with a graph and call it on my index.js, even when I move that other page inside the pages folder it doesnt work. How am I supposed to call multiple API requests?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling a page component from another page component. If you want to make multiple API calls from your index page, just add them to `getStaticProps` in that page.

Comment: @juliomalves Ah, okay. Can you please create an answer showing how to do that? I have tried before but was only able to return a single value, not both.

Comment: You can check @bmdev answer. His last code snippet shows how to structure the index page. If you require help with the logic inside the `getStaticProps` you'll need to provide additional code about what you have in it.

Comment: @juliomalves My code is already there. I mean pulling multiple fetch functions, how am I supposed to do that and return multiple different values? His answer does not show that,. I already have a getStaticProps working on my page pulling a single API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next.js does a lot of magic to handle server-side rendering, static-site generation and code splitting, and it does it all from within the `/pages` folder. It's important to know that components within the `/pages` folder work a little differently from a regular React component. Here are some tips for you that should solve your problem.

#### 1. Put your page components inside the `/pages` folder.

Components inside this folder can have a default export (the component), along with named exports (the additional Next.js-specific functions like `getStaticProps`). If Next.js finds the exported functions, it will run them.

#### 2. Use `next/dynamic` only for dynamic imports.

Dynamic imports are lazy-loaded -- this will affect Next.js' automatic code-splitting and potentially server-side rendering. I don't know the exact inner workings, but my guess is dynamically-loading a Page component (which are special in Next) is probably what's breaking things. I tend to only use dynamic imports when I have a 3rd-party component that breaks SSR, so I need to dynamically import it so it's not server-side rendered.

---

The simplest way to handle this is probably:

in `/pages/index.js`:

```js
import Example from '../path/to/example';

export default (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>My page component</p>
    <Example />
  </div>
);

export async function getStaticProps() {
    return {
        props: {
            data: // ...
        }
    };
}
```

---

With this solution above, you *can* use dynamic imports as well -- what matters is that you have your Next.js-specific function exported from the file in `/pages` immediately:

in `/pages/index.js`:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Example = dynamic(() => import('../components/example'));

export default (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>My page component</p>
    <Example />
  </div>
);

export async function getStaticProps() {
    return {
        props: {
            data: // ...
        }
    };
}
```

#### Update to solve "My getStaticProps function is in my example.js file, and my issue is that it is not being triggered.":

Next.js will only call a `getStaticProps` function that is exported from a file in the `/pages` directory. If you want to define your `getStaticProps` method from another directory, you can do that, but you need to import it into `/pages` and then re-export it like so:

in `/components/example.js`:

```js
export default () => (
 // ... component ...
);

export function getStaticProps() {
 // ... function ...
};
```

and in `/pages/index.js`:

```js
import Example, { getStaticProps } from '../components/example';

export default Example;

export {
  getStaticProps
}
```

This should work. However, you *can't* import Example using dynamic imports in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... but how do I pull multiple requests from a single getStaticProps function? For example, I need to fetch data from 'hello.com' and 'helloTwo.com'

Comment: np! You can use async/await for back-to-back calls like you would otherwise: `const helloData = await myApi.fetch('hello.com'); const helloTwoData = await myApi.fetch('helloTwo.com');` I'm not sure exactly what end goal you're trying to accomplish, but it may also make sense to split up your work into individual pages. You can have `/pages/index.js` with its getStaticProps fn, and `/pages/hello-two/index.js` with its own getStaticProps fn

Comment: Thank you for this! But where is myApi coming from, and how do I return the values of each fetch? Also, can I import the getStaticProps function from another page to my index? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I added my getStaticProps code in my initial question.

Comment: I see -- I was using "myApi" as an example -- after seeing your updated question, using `fetch` will work just fine -- you can apply the same approach of back-to-back `await` calls as I mentioned in my previous comment. I am going to update my answer to more directly answer your question now that I see your edit